# RSA encryption between Swift and C#

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cryptography, rsa

I need to build the Apple client part to an existing server that is written in .Net/C#. The client should run on OS X and iOS. Part of the communication is done using encrypted data, the C# source being something like

```
    string privateKey = "xyz…=" // Base64 encoded
    string publicKey  = "abc…=" // Base64 encoded

    byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedBytes)
    {
        CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 /* PROV_RSA_FULL */ };
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
        rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey));

        return rsaProvider.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, false);
    }
```

This looks quite simple, but I cannot find a way to implement the `encrypt` counterpart in Swift.

The `publicKey` data consists solely of Modulus and Exponent numbers. I can extract the Modulus number from the public key with `rsaProvider.ExportParameters(false).Modulus`, the Exponent being `[1, 0, 1]` as usual.

How can I use the Modulus number (or the `publicKey` string constant itself) in my Swift application on the OS X / iOS client side, and how do I encrypt a plaintext there that can be decrypted on the C# server side?

I understand that Apple is not very fond of introducing cryptographic keys in such a low-level fashion, but there seems to be a possibility to import such a key into the keychain and then use it for encryption.

I have the building blocks (`SecItem…()`, `SecKeyEncrypt()`, etc.) but I cannot get it up and running.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/iccir/SignAndVerify repo. It doesn't have encryption part, but it shows how to import OpenSSL private/public keys on OS X and iOS. Once you have your key imported, you can use it for encryption.

Comment: Thank you @AlexSkalozub for the pointer. I'll try to understand how it is done there, but part of my problem is implementing it in Swift…

Comment: Added an example for iOS in Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work on iOS.

For OS X, you need a slightly different approach (`SecItemImport` instead of `SecItemAdd`).

```
import UIKit
import Security

let publicKey = "MIIBCgKCAQEAxWp6GqUOG3xuMhaE0Eeb0eOqbPHE2lRQ53qg2A1rInWdBTVtQaU82Yurv6rFoz++jswiHf3VBy3plhalF+1CTruuzSqVUjpeWTGFppoIym8andVtGLP5mN56Ks7z8VxwQ4MvmM5lGqw3YX6NWVNirWTGdJsqiplmhkAZXFAY43ivwTFSbQ4Uhx7SA0PK537V6je5MJ9edaWpKc1HoGH/bZG9/qrunv2Wam0w9qb8/TOsNvxdgBFs9WZaU0amkNb4h94y9ZrJKYsRGTngDAZ/uA+WK5ZM+Dz3GelsDUErvlUlswLyhQKYPPGn+QlVbMF4drUZ6piZWPmvpY2a/iyRcwIDAQAB"

let keyData = NSData(base64EncodedString: publicKey, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)

var dictionary: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
    kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
    kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
    kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
    kSecAttrApplicationTag: "mypubkeyappspecifictag",
    kSecValueData: keyData!,
    kSecReturnRef: true
];

var err = SecItemAdd(dictionary, nil);

if ((err != noErr) && (err != errSecDuplicateItem)) {
    print("error loading public key");
}

var keyRef: AnyObject?;
err = SecItemCopyMatching(dictionary, &keyRef);
if (err == noErr) {
    if let keyRef = keyRef as! SecKeyRef? {
        let plaintext = "12345";

        let plaintextLen = plaintext.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        let plaintextBytes = [UInt8](plaintext.utf8);

        var encryptedLen: Int = SecKeyGetBlockSize(keyRef);
        var encryptedBytes = [UInt8](count: encryptedLen, repeatedValue: 0);

        err = SecKeyEncrypt(keyRef, SecPadding.PKCS1, plaintextBytes, plaintextLen, &encryptedBytes, &encryptedLen);
        if (err != noErr) {
            print(encryptedBytes);
        }
    }
}

SecItemDelete(dictionary);
```

Please note that public key for iOS should be stripped of ASN1 preamble, as specified [here](http://blog.flirble.org/2011/01/05/rsa-public-key-openssl-ios/#whats-in-a-key).

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the code snippet now with different combinations. 
OS X: still have to fiddle with `SecItemImport`.
iOS: accessing the keychain had no success with my key, but success with your example key — except that the `keyRef` returned by `SecItemCopyMatching` is `nil` and therefore the actual encryption cannot be executed.

Comment: It is sure iOS only, for OS X you need a bit different code. And read the last line (and the linked article) carefully, you need to strip your public key's prefix before using it on iOS.

Comment: iOS has priority anyway, so I'll skip the OS X version for now. But is the "CSP Blob" that's imported in the C# example actually a PKCS#1 object with an ASN.1 header?

Comment: Addition: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288397/import-csp-blob-exported-from-net-into-python-pycropto the Blob has a proprietary Microsoft format, but starting with the pure modulus and exponent numbers it is possible to construct a PKCS#1 structure.

Comment: Sure you cannot use MS-specific blob with iOS or OS X. You need to convert into something acceptable first. I have no idea how it looks like (and too lazy to actually check it), but if you have an example of valid CSP blob, please post it here.

Comment: Please see my answer with the complete process. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I found the right combination. Alex Skalozub's answer was a great help in this process.

Here's my process step by step:

It starts with the public key string that was given on the server side. This had been generated previously this way: (C# .Net)

```
CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 /* PROV_RSA_FULL */ };

// generate key pair with given size
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(4096, cspParams);

string publicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(false));
string privateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(true));
```

These keys are stored internally as string constants and are then, after extracting them from their base64 representation, imported when the server is initializing:

```
CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 /* PROV_RSA_FULL */ };
// no key generation this time:
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey));
```

Since these "CSP Blobs" are a proprietary Microsoft Cryptographic API structure, I had to use them and extract the low-level RSA numbers (*n* and *e* for the public key; *d* for the private key was not really needed here): (C# .Net)

```
RSAParameters pub = rsaProvider.ExportParameters(false);
string n = Convert.ToBase64String(pub.Modulus);
string e = Convert.ToBase64String(pub.Exponent);

RSAParameters priv = rsaProvider.ExportParameters(true);
string d = Convert.ToBase64String(priv.D);
```

Next step is building an Apple-compatible (i.e. non standard conforming) key string from the numbers. I used Python with the PyCrypto package:

```
import base64
from Crypto.Util import asn1

def b64ToNum(b64str):
  byteStr = base64.b64decode(b64str)
  num = 0L
  for digit in byteStr:
    num = num * 256 + ord(digit)
  return num

n_b64 = "..."   # copied from C# output
e_b64 = "..."   # copied from C# output

n = b64ToNum(n_b64)
e = b64ToNum(e_b64)

seq = asn1.DerSequence()
seq[:] = [ n, e ]  ## Standard would be [ 0, n, e ] !!!

print s.encode("base64").replace("\n", "")
```

This produces a base64-encoded public key string that can be used for insertion in the iOS keychain, as shown in Alex' code (`SecItemAdd`, `SecItemCopyMatching`).

I also verified that the C# code can successfully decrypt data I encrypt on the iOS side.